# Asynchronous Java RMI

Tags: java, asynchronous, rmi

Recently I have needed to use RMI, and I know enough for what I need to do, but one thing is intriguing me as I revisit this topic. Is it possible to make asynchronous RMI calls to the same service on the server?

Let's say I have n threads on the client and a single server-side object--call it S. S has a single method that I want to call from my client-side threads, but I don't want it to block as it has no shared resource to worry about.

Any ideas? Or is this something that is just better left to other methods?

Comment: Have you actually seen RMI blocking when you call the same method from multiple client threads? Because I'm not aware of this being part of the spec; you should see the same behavior as calling a local method from multiple threads. Of course, depending on how the schedule executes threads, it may *appear* to be blocking ...

Comment: no problem. to do it async and not blocking your client thread, you have to arrange the call in a different thread and ignore the return. Or use one of those 'light weight rmi alternatives' that supports async call natively.

Comment: My LipeRMI fork natively supports asynchronous RMI. https://github.com/terraframe/lipermi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no issues with doing this.  It is the equivalent of multiple clients calling the same service at the same time from the service's perspective.

Any server side object should be written to be safe for concurrent access.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should work with something like JMS queue for asynchronic calls on an J2EE architecture. It works perfectly in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Redisson](http://redisson.org) framework remote service could be registered on same node with client side Redisson instance and even on same JVM shared with client side Redisson instance.

Let's assume `YourServiceImpl` contains method you need to invoke remotely and implements `YourService` interface.

YourServiceImpl should be registered in Redisson via RemoteService object:

```
YourService yourService = new YourServiceImpl();

RRemoteService remoteService = redisson.getRemoteService();
remoteService.register(YourService.class, yourService);
```

Remote invocations could be made in asynchronous manner with separate interface marked 
with `@RRemoteAsync` annotation. Method signatures should be match with same methods in remote interface.
Each method should return `org.redisson.core.RFuture` object. It extends `java.util.concurrent.Future` 
and `java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage` interfaces and 
has few useful methods.

```
public interface YourService {

    Long someMethod1(Long param1, String param2);

    void someMethod2(MyObject param);

    MyObject someMethod3();

}

// async interface for YourService
@RRemoteAsync(YourService.class)
public interface YourServiceAsync {

    RFuture<Long> someMethod1(Long param1, String param2);

    RFuture<Void> someMethod2(MyObject param);

}
```

To invoke method remotely use `YourServiceAsync` interface:

```
RRemoteService remoteService = redisson.getRemoteService();
YourServiceAsync asyncService = remoteService.get(YourServiceAsync.class);

RFuture<Long> res = asyncService.someMethod1(12L, "param");
res.thenApply(r -> {
    ...
});
```

More documentation is [here](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services#91-remote-service)