# Spring Async RMI Call

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback, rmi

Is it possible to invoke Java RMI asynchronously?  I'd like my RMI call to return immediately and for the server to invoke a callback once a task is completed.

I'd currently using RMI support from Spring framework, and i couldn't find any documentation describing it in spring, I suspect I'll need to implement it myself.  Please provide examples if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902393/asynchronous-java-rmi

Comment: Steen, thanks for referring to this post.  My situation is slightly different though, since my remote call might fail and I'd like to post a reply back to notify user on success/failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RMI is synchronous and doesn't support callbacks as far as I know.

JMS is the Java EE way to make asynch calls.  If you're using Spring, it would be a message-driven POJO.

Another place to look, since you're already using Spring, is either Spring [Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) or Spring [Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration).  I'd try either of those before I wrote it myself.

But if that doesn't do it for you, your suspicion is correct - you'll have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't look Spring batch and Spring Integration but without changing the RMI protocol the only way to implement asynchronous call is to span a new thread that wait for the result from the server and this is not a true asynchronous call.

The way to have true asynchronous call is to:

1. Implement RMI with NIO.
2. When the proxy is invoked put the request on the NIO selector and return immediately a result future to the caller.
3. Each request has to have a unique request id and when a response with that id arrive from the server the right future should be resolved.

There is only one implementation of such [async RMI](https://github.com/barakb/asyncrmi)  (I am not sure it is production ready yet).

Here is a good [explanation](http://barakb.github.io/asyncrmi/asynchronous-calls.html) with sequence diagram